# How can I create a file from any data so that MDA (Measure Data Analyzer) can read it?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to read data from an oscilloscope into MDA (INCA data reading software), reason being my seniors know how to operate MDA better than other applications like MATLAB. I am wondering how I can format the data in a way that MDA accepts it. I have tried converting the data I get into .DAT format but it has not been working. I am guessing the data must be in a specific format in .DAT to be used.

Image of .DAT file MDA can read. Most of it is gibberish like what you see on the bottom:

[image: Description]

Comment: Could you provide more information like how does a .DAT file looks like if it is compatible with MDA? Just open it in an text editor like notepad++ and show the format. What is your data looking like? What are the dimensions of the matrces?  Generally you can use the command fprintf() [link](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) to write data formatted to files....

Comment: The MDA [web page](http://www.etas.com/en/products/mda.php) says that it can read data in "MDF or ASCII format". So you will have to read the manual and see what these file formats look like, and then format your data that way.